# IELTS, TEF for express entry Canada. Where to take them.. could be anywhere I like?

Tags: immigration, canada, canadian-citizens, ielts, language-test

I'm applying for an express entry residency for Canada. Can I take the IELTS and the TEF exams ANYWHERE I want to or are there specific institutions which are valid for this procedure? Can't seem to find that piece of info.

Answer (score 2):

Organisations like [IDP](http://www.idp.com/india/ielts) and [BritishCouncil](http://www.britishcouncil.in/exam/ielts) conduct exams for IELTS General and Academic.

IELTS test results from these two organisations are globally accepted.

Comment: Just be aware that Canada requires the General test. The Academic test is not acceptable.